# App Engine appending items to ListProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I think I'm loosing my mind, why doens't the following work?

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    childrenKeys = db.ListProperty(str,indexed=False,default=None)

p = Parent.get_or_insert(key_name='somekey')
p.childrenKeys = p.childrenKeys.append('newchildkey')
p.put()
```

I get this error:

```
BadValueError: Property childrenKeys is required
```

The doc says:

> *default* is the default value for the list property. If None, the
>   default is an empty list. A list property can define a custom
>   validator to disallow the empty list.

So the way I see it, I'm getting the default (an empty list) and appending a new value to it and the saving it.

Comment: you probably want a `StringListProperty` rather than `ListProperty(str)`, in any case. (Although if this works for you at all, something may have changed in a recent SDK that makes them equivalent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should remove the `p.childrenKeys` assignment:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    childrenKeys = db.ListProperty(str,indexed=False,default=[])

p = Parent.get_or_insert('somekey')
p.childrenKeys.append('newchkey')
p.put()
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace this:

```
p.childrenKeys = p.childrenKeys.append('newchildkey')
```

with this:

```
p.childrenKeys.append('newchildkey')
```

`append()` returns `None`, which can't be assigned to `p.childrenKeys`.

Comment: Isn't it suppose to return an empty list as the doc says? It can't be that empty list in Python are equivalent to None, are they?

Comment: p.childrenKeys does return an empty list.  p.childrenKeys.append() returns None, because that's the behavior of the append() method of a list.  The issue here was the assignment of None to p.childrenKeys, which isn't allowed by ListProperty.  (You can assign the empty list to a ListProperty, which within the datastore is represented by having no properties of that name.)